# Будет ли JVM считать объект неиспользуемым, если он будет в коллекции?

Tags: java, объекты

Искал информацию про объекты, и на одном сайте нашел, что

> Если просто создать объект и не присвоить его никакой переменной, то Java-машина создаст его и тут же объявит его мусором (неиспользуемым объектом). А через некоторое время удалит его в процессе «сборки мусора».

Так ли это работает, если я буду использовать коллекцию?

```
ArrayList.add(new Object(...))
```

Т.к. я и дальше после добавления такого экземпляра в ArrayList могу использовать его.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет. Если объект добавлен в коллекцию, то фактически вы присвоили его элементу коллекции. Пока есть ссылка на `ArrayList`, содержащий этот объект, сборщик мусора его не тронет.

Answer (score 3):

Добавлю, что JVM предусматривает специальный механизм разрешающий сборку мусора даже если объект находится в коллекции. Делается это через [WeakReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html)

```
 MyObject myObject;
 myList = new ArrayList<WeakReference<MyObject>>();
 myList.add(new WeakReference<MyObject>(myObject));
```

в таком случае сборщик сможет убрать объект `myObject` даже если он находится в коллекции.

Иногда это бывает полезно.